# What is the maximum number of records that can be retrieved by postgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

When retrieving records using `SELECT` in postgres, what is maximum number of records that can be retrieved? Can it return a maximum of 10 million records at a single time if I wanted it too? Or can it only return a specific amount (ex. 5,000) in order to encourage using `LIMIT` and `OFFSET`?

Comment: The number of rows in the table.

Comment: @KenWhite Can you take another look at my question? I edited it incase it was unclear.

Comment: Your question was clear, as was my comment that answered it. The maximum number of rows (records) that can be returned is the number of rows in the table, unless you do something foolish like a Cartesian join, in which case it would return the maximum number of rows in that SELECT or until your computer crashed because it ran out of memory, whichever comes first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no limit to the number of result rows in a query.

If your client collects the whole result in memory, that poses a limit, but most clients can be configured not to do that.